# What matching algorithm could I use?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

I would need some help because I don't know what algorithm i could use for the following (I use python) :

- Steve is 25 and he buys everyday orange juice
- Maria is 23 and she likes to buy smoothies
  Steve & Maria tastes are pretty much the same.
- Juan is 16 and he only drinks sodas
  Juan tastes are not the same as Steve and Maria.

====================================================

I would like to use a matching algorithm that will detect the users who have the same drink preference and a close age. To continue with the example, Steve and Maria would be matched together but not Juan. Which one should I use ?

Comment: The task is pretty vague. You could use a simple data structure containing name, age and preference and then just loop a list of those, creating matches with simple if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @klutt that your task is pretty vague. There are two approaches that come to mind, but not knowing more details about your problem does limit the details I can provide in my answer that would help you. I am interpreting the question as if you are taking in raw text and might want to process more sentences that have very similar semantic and syntactical structure.

**An algorithmic approach:**
Assuming that your word choices are static in their semantic meaning (Maria **is** 23 ... Steve **is** 25), we can parse each sentence and identify tokens like **is** or **and** or **same** and essentially perform lexical analysis on the text... from here, you could continue thinking about how you would go about matching and so forth... but this is rather complicated...

**Neural Network approach:**
If you are taking in raw text in the form of sentences, it's a problem that's not straight forward to solve using a top-down algorithmic approach.
You could take an approach with neural networks that trains a model to solve your problem, but then again what you seem to be asking is quite complex since there are multiple "facts" within each sentence that are not semantically related. For example, your second sentence identifies that Maria is 23 but at the end of that sentence there is a comparison between Steve and Maria. And your first sentence only identifies Steve as 25.
Even if you chunk raw text into sentences, you would have to have a very fine tuned neural network architecture and a lot of training data to get remotely close to your goal.

---

Now, both of those solutions are very complex... but if you wanted to create an application that collects this data (via a form or prompt) and puts it into a structured format (like a json or xml object) to organize and store the data in memory (perhaps writing out to a database or file for persistent storage), that might be a good route to go down.

This can serve as a good lesson in how to think about data as well. It is one thing if you have a pool of thousands of sentences, just raw data that you need to organize for quantitative purposes (classic qualitative -> quantitative problems). It is another thing if you are going to be collecting this data. If you are going to be collecting data, having a program that collects and organizes names, ages, and drink preferences (and then organizes that data within certain data structures), ***then we can talk about matching algorithms.***

I will also add here that if you do have structured data, [Collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) (mentioned by Shridhar) is a great starting place.

Answer (score 0):

[Collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) best suits your needs.

> In the newer, narrower sense, collaborative filtering is a method of
> making automatic predictions (filtering) about the interests of a user
> by collecting preferences or taste information from many users
> (collaborating). The underlying assumption of the collaborative
> filtering approach is that if a person A has the same opinion as a
> person B on an issue, A is more likely to have B's opinion on a
> different issue than that of a randomly chosen person. For example, a
> collaborative filtering recommendation system for television tastes
> could make predictions about which television show a user should like
> given a partial list of that user's tastes (likes or dislikes).[3]
> Note that these predictions are specific to the user, but use
> information gleaned from many users. This differs from the simpler
> approach of giving an average (non-specific) score for each item of
> interest, for example based on its number of votes.